# Pointing a subdomain to a subfolder using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

My webhost automatically forwards all requests to *.mydomain.com to the toplevel domain mydomain.com.

I wanted to map any subdomain to a specific folder on my toplevel domain. i.e. sub.example.com must be mapped to example.com/someFolder (**without** change in the address bar).

After digging around on the net, I came up with this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?[^.]+\.example\.com.*$
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/myfolder/$1 [L]
```

This seems to work well, except for one problem: When I go to the URL sub.example.com, the URL in the address bar changes to example.com/myfolder . But, when I do something like sub.example.com/login - this maps to "example.com/sub/login" properly without the change in the address bar. Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is your webhost btw?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

only small change needed:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?[^.]+\.example\.com.*$
RewriteRule (.*) myfolder/$1 [L]
```

stripped out http:// at the rule which tells Apache to send a Redirect header instead of proper server-side rewrite.

Comment: Sorry, it was my fault, I was doing a PHP redirect with the absolute (direct) URL within that so it looked as if it was not working! Thanks!