# htaccess rewriting for root to sub directory

Tags: .htaccess

I want to point my subdirectory folder like this

www.FOLDERNAME.SITE_NAME.net

and write now its working like this

www.SITE_NAME.net/FOLDER_NAME

I already made a domain for my folder

I tried many htaccess but no luck at all.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What's the use case for this? What have you tried so far?

Comment: can you paste the htacces for www.SITE_NAME.net/FOLDER_NAME format which was not working and htaccess for www.SITE_NAME.FOLDER_NAME.net which is not working , so that we can help you out

Comment: This is a duplicate question actually. View this question for an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588371/pointing-a-subdomain-to-a-subfolder-using-htaccess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi did you try this one.

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^FOLDERNAME\.SITE_NAME\.net$ [NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/FOLDERNAME/
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /FOLDERNAME/$1
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^FOLDERNAME\.SITE_NAME\.net$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(/)?$ FOLDERNAME/index.php [L]
```

I did not Try but I am sure it will work out your problem.

feel free to ask on the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot rajat I replaced foldername and sitename as per my requirement and itz work like a charm thanks a ton man!!!

Answer (score 0):

TRY ( not tested )

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule folder_name\.%{HTTP_HOST}%\.net
www.%{HTTP_HOST}%\.net/folder_name [NC,R=301,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay I am working on your possible solution.