# .htaccess write rule for subdomain to subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to rewrite requests to a subdomain to a sub-folder on the site in question.

The subdomain is `dev.my-domain.co.za` (yes, it has a hyphen in it)

The folder it needs to internally reference is `my-domain.co.za/dev.my-domain.co.za`

I don't want it to redirect, but to rewrite, so that the user just sees `http://dev.my-domain.co.za/...`

I found various examples here on StackOverflow, but I was unable to get them to work in my scenario. So I figure it's best I ask and explain my exact situation.

There is going to be a Wordpress site in the sub-folder. I am assuming it is okay to call it via a sub-domain (if you happen to know, please advise). Otherwise, if there are issues, I can ask that question separately in a WP related forum.

So far I tried this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev\.domesticflights\-southafrica\.co\.za.*$
RewriteRule (.*) dev\.domesticflights\-southafrica\.co\.za/$1 [L]
```

Which is my attempt to apply this (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1588394/1092677)) to my scenario

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?[^.]+\.example\.com.*$
RewriteRule (.*) myfolder/$1 [L]
```

I tried adapting many other examples, but none work in my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these rules to internally redirect from

`dev.my-domain.co.za` to `my-domain.co.za/dev.my-domain.co.za`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www)(.+)\.(my-domain\.co\.za)$
RewriteRule ^ http://%2/%1.%2 [P]
```

Comment: Thanks Jack. Seems to have had no effect whatsoever. I am beginning to wonder if this server environment is set up strangely (it's a server and host I am not familiar with).

Comment: Ok, check to see if your htaccess file use is enabled in the apache config. It should be `AllowOverride All` Also I updated my answer because you will need to proxypass to the subfolder using the `[P]` flag or apache will do a redirect.